# Trying to round a calculation to 2 decimal place in a new column in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

So I am trying to...

> Write a SELECT statement that returns these column names and data from the Products table:
>
> - product_name
> - list_price
> - discount_percent
> - discount_amount
>
>   - A column that’s calculated from the previous two columns
> - discount_price
>
>   - A column that’s calculated from the previous three columns
>
> Round the discount_amount and discount_price columns to 2 decimal places.
>
> Sort the result set by discount price in descending sequence.
>
> Use the LIMIT clause so the result set contains only the first 5 rows.

So far I have

```
USE my_guitar_shop;

SELECT product_name, list_price, discount_percent,
             CONCAT(discount_percent / 100 * list_price)
                AS discount_amount
FROM products
```

I am able to return `discount_amount`, but not able to be able to round the column to 2 decimal places.

How would I also go about returning a second column? Such as

```
ROUND(list_price - discount_amount, 2) 
AS discount_price
```

It says it doesn't recognize discount_amount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROUND()` instead of CONCAT.

```
ROUND(discount_percent / 100 * list_price, 2)
```

The first argument is the number to round. The second argument is how many decimal places to round to.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round

> Blockquote
>   How would I also go about returning a second column? Such as

```
ROUND(list_price - discount_amount, 2) 
AS discount_price
```

You can't reuse an alias like that. I would just repeat the expression

```
ROUND(list_price - (discount_percent / 100 * list_price), 2) 
AS discount_price
```

Comment: Seems so simple the way you put it -_- Thank you so much!

Comment: So that totally worked and I accepted it, but I added some more info if you wouldn't mind looking at it